# JavaScript IP Range Validation is second ip is greater than first ip

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, range

Hello I am a javascript noob and was writing a validator for an IP range. For example 1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2 is a valid range however I want to make sure that the first IP is not greater than the second IP. 2.2.2.2-1.1.1.1 should return false. What is the best strategy to go about this problem, should I try to convert each IP string to a map of integers and then compare them one by one? Should I iterate a for loop 1-4 and compare the first value before the . and then the second etc.

```
ipRangeValidator: function(value)
{
    if (!value)
        return true;
    var split = value.split('-');
    if (!split || split.length > 2 || split.length === 0) {
        return 'Input only an IP or single IP Range';
    }

    var ips = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < split.length; ++x) {
        var ip = split[x];
        if (isValidIpV6Address(ip)) { 
        } else if (isValidIpV4Address(ip)) {
        } else {
            return ip + ' is not a valid IP address';
        }
        ips.push(ip);
    }
    if (ips.length > 1) {
       if(true) {            //The Line I am struggling with
           return 'The first IP is greater than the second IP';
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Here is another fun way: `const ip2num = s => new DataView(new Uint8ClampedArray(s.split(".")).buffer).getUint32(); console.log(ip2num("1.1.1.1") < ip2num("2.2.2.2"));`, but i think you are prematurely optimizing. Either of your mentioned potential solutions should work. As it should be hidden in some short, and well named utility function, noone cares. Just do something that works, give it a readable function name, comment it, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something, like that work for you?

```js
const validRange = '1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2',
      invalidRange = '2.2.2.2-1.1.1.1',
      anotherInvalidRange = '1.1.3.1-1.1.2.1',
      invalidIp = '1.1.300.1-1.1.1.1',
      
      isRangeValid = range => {
        const [rangeStart, rangeEnd] = range.split('-'),
              [s1,s2,s3,s4] = rangeStart.split('.'),
              [e1,e2,e3,e4] = rangeEnd.split('.')
        return [s1,s2,s3,s4].some(o => o>255 || o<0) || [e1,e2,e3,e4].some(o => o>255 || o<0) ?
          'range contains invalid IP' :
          s1>e1 || s2>e2 || s3>e3 || s4>e4 ?
          'range start is greater than range end' :
          'range is valid'
      }
      
console.log(isRangeValid(validRange))
console.log(isRangeValid(invalidRange))
console.log(isRangeValid(anotherInvalidRange))
console.log(isRangeValid(invalidIp))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: You need to  split on "." here `rangeStart.split('-'),` No more Nemirov for you

Comment: @mplungjan : Thanks. Got it fixed and appended extra IP validation, that crossed my mind while I was updating

Comment: Nice answer, also would update it so that two identical IPs are invalid range, e.g. 1.1.1.1-1.1.1.1 should be invalid.

Comment: @KillerKode: To me, the range that contains a single IP is still a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
const pad = (num) => String("00"+num).slice(-3);
const ipRange = rng => {
  let [ip1,ip2] = rng.split("-");
  ip1 = ip1.split(".").map(num => pad(num)).join('.')
  ip2 = ip2.split(".").map(num => pad(num)).join('.')
  return ip1>ip2;
};
console.log(
  ipRange("1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2")
)  
console.log(
  ipRange("2.2.2.2-1.1.1.1")
)
```